# Dynamic route request render not working, backend express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I want to try dynamic route request but It's not working properly. And here I explain my coding style step by step.

```
 <nav class="main-nav" ng-show="global.user.user_type!='admin'" ng-repeat="mMenu in Mainmenu">
  <a href="/views/adminpanel/{{mMenu.WebAddress}}" id="load1" ng-click="geturl(mMenu.WebAddress)">{{mMenu.MenuName}}</a>
</nav>
```

This code contain URL link and It's load every time with a variable that is web address link. And the link is something like that - http://localhost/views/adminpanel/about.html

In AngularJS Controller contain the code -

```
$scope.geturl = function(url)
    {
        var params = {
            url1 : '/views/adminpanel/'+url
        }

        $http({'method' : 'post', url : 'views/adminpanel/'+url, data: params
         }).success(function(data)
        {
        }).
        error(function(data){

        })
    }
```

configuring and using ngRoute -

```
 when('/views/adminpanel/:url', {
     controller: 'homeCntrl',
     templateUrl: 'views/adminpanel/:url'

})
```

In server side (Express) :

Routing HTTP requests, Configuring middleware and Rendering HTML views

```
app.post('/views/adminpanel/:url',auth.requiresLogin, users.geturl);

exports.geturl= function(req,res)
{
    var url = req.body.url1;
    res.render(url);

}
```

This is all about my rendering process but It's not working. In browser It only shows the URL link but not shows any content. How can I solve It any idea?

Comment: that `templateUrl` doesn't look valid to me.  are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Thank you Claies. I checked console but It's really fine and not get any error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing things:

- first of all you have a link together with a ngClick: you should have either of those
- your ngClick has an empty `success` function, so it does nothing with the template
- you have a route set with express that matches with the ngRoute (btw, POST is usually used to create resources, you should GET the template)
- your templateUrl is going to send a GET request to (literally) `/views/adminpanel/:url`, it does not replace `:url`

To fix it:

- set a different endpoint for your APIs
- use a GET endpoint instead of a POST
- change the ngRoute to:

  ```
  when('/views/adminpanel/:url', {
    controller: 'homeCntrl',
    templateUrl: function(param) {
      return '/api/<path>/' + param.url;
    }
  })
  ```
- remove the ngClick from the `<a>`